# arcpy.analysis.Near within a for loop

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, proximity, error-000496

I want to calculate Distance between Points from two different polygon tables. I'm using this code but I get this error code. Any idea?

```py
import arcpy
​
search_radius = "5000 Meters"
​
shapefile1 = r"D:\Masterarbeit\Arcpy_Kanonymity\ZFG_Data_Aachen_K.shp"
shapefile2 = r"D:\Masterarbeit\Arcpy_Kanonymity\Edge_Ka.shp"
​
#arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(shapefile1, 'GPS_Original')
#arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(shapefile2, 'GPS_masking')
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute('GPS_Original', 'CLEAR_SELECTION')
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute('GPS_masking', 'CLEAR_SELECTION')
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shapefile1, ['OBJECTID']) as GPS_distance:
    for x in GPS_distance:
        print(x[0])
        print('"OBJECTID" = {}'.format(x[0]))
        arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute('GPS_Original', 'NEW_SELECTION', '"OBJECTID" = {}'.format(x[0]))
        arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute('GPS_masking', 'NEW_SELECTION', '"OBJECTID" = {}'.format(x[0]))
        arcpy.analysis.Near('GPS_masking', 'GPS_Original',search_radius, 'NO_LOCATION', 'NO_ANGLE', 'PLANAR','NEAR_DIST')
        arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute('GPS_masking', 'CLEAR_SELECTION')
        arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute('GPS_Original', 'CLEAR_SELECTION')

136 
"OBJECTID" = 136
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ExecuteError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [51]:
Line 20:    arcpy.analysis.Near('GPS_masking', 'GPS_Original',search_radius, 'NO_LOCATION', 'NO_ANGLE', 'GEODESIC','NEAR_DIST')

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\analysis.py, in Near:
Line 1875:  raise e

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\analysis.py, in Near:
Line 1872:  retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.Near_analysis(*gp_fixargs((in_features, near_features, search_radius, location, angle, method, field_names), True)))

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py, in <lambda>:
Line 511:   return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))

ExecuteError: ERROR 000496: Tabelle wird bearbeitet.
Fehler beim Ausführen von (Near).
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that the source layer is being edited.

`arcpy.analysis.Near` adds fields to the input layer (the first argument in the list). Adding fields changes the schema so it requires a schema lock.

In this case, the input layer is `'GPS_Original'`. You seem to have had (and commented out) some code to create that layer. If you are running your code without that, it's using some existing layer from your workspace.

If you are running this in a context (like a Jupyter Notebook, or from an interactive Python interpreter), resetting the session, context or kernel *may* fix the problem. If it failed part-way through execution, the failed run could hold a schema lock. Resetting would release it if this was the case.

If you have either the workspace, the feature layer or the source layer open in any software, it could cause this. For instance, your workspace may be a file GDB, so having the FGDB layer on a map in ArcPro would cause this. Similarly, if your source is the shapefile (with the `arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer` call commented out, it's hard to tell where your layer is coming from), having *that* open in ArcPro could cause this as well. I would recommend closing all instances of ArcPro (and other similar programs) then trying again. I have had problems even having something open in ArcCatalog in the past.

As a side note, you seem to be doing a lot of layer select operations in your loop, some of which may not be necessary. Consider using [the `where_clause` on `arcpy.da.SearchCursor`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm) (you may write the where clause [as you would in ArcPro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/navigation/sql-reference-for-elements-used-in-query-expressions.htm)) which may give you significantly better performance.